# WebSecurity in ASP .NET User Profile is not creating

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am working with WebSecurity in my asp.net website and I write a code in _AppStart.cshtml is

```
@{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Membership","UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
}
```

and I am creating my account through the following code

```
 if(!WebSecurity.UserExists(username))
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username,password);

            }
```

But the User Profile is not creating. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using [this override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)?  Because the third parameter takes a list of property values, which would be stored in the user profile feature.